# How to specify structure in which order matters in a class diagram

Tags: uml

In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35295055/how-to-set-sequence-relationship-between-classes) I was trying to achieve the idea of ordering the classes. Although the example I presented wasn't appropriate.

So here is the situation I want to ascribe by UML class diagram:

In ODT document I have something called `figure`. The figure is comprised of two atomic elements: `image` and `title`(of the image). The standard allows me to put the `title`, either on top of the `image` or bellow the it. Although In my application the `title` will always be beneath the `image` like this:

[image]

So in my case I want to submit the (more specific) information that the title must be beneath the image (although the standard does not obligate so). Thus I came up to the idea of making order in my class diagram (this is first, then this, then this, etc...). Because in my case that matters.

Here is my despaired attempt:

[image]

Is there any approach to present that information through a UML Class Diagram?

Comment: Looks ok. Just remove the two numbers. And add a multiplicity of 1 to the Image/Title ends. (Eventually to the other side too.)

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Kilian.
But lets pretend that you don't know about the explanatory text and the 'Figure' picture from my original post. All the information you have is my simple class diagram. How would you know that the image must be first and the title must be second with the space progress (or with the progression of reading)? I don't believe my diagram is bearing that information.

Comment: Just add a constraint that explains this and you are done.

Comment: Adding constraints is not something I am familiar with. May be it is platform specific. I am using StarUML version: 5.0.2.1570

Comment: It's fairly easy. Make a note and place the constraint text in curly brackets. Eg. `{Title must be placed under Image}`. Either attach this to the links or if the tool does not allow it, attach it to `Figure`.

Comment: Of course "order" is a complex thing. Depending on its semantic it can be expressed in many ways. Staying informal here is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UML meta-model, there are meta-elements called `Class` and `Property`. An instance of a `Class` meta-element (e.g., called `Figure`) may own instances of a `Property` meta-element. Each instance of a `Property` meta-element has a type (e.g., `Image` and `Figure`). Both of the instances of the `Property` meta-element in your model are unnamed, which, unfortunately, makes it difficult to refer to them. Nonetheless, all of the instances of the `Property` meta-element that an instance of the `Class` meta-element owns are *ordered*. When you create a property in a UML tool, you generally add it to the end of an ordered list.

In your diagram there are two unnamed properties that are already ordered (implicitly, based on which you created first in the tool). This order can be seen *and changed* in a UML compliant tool. Here is an example UML model:

[image]

I strongly recommend you name all your properties, as I have done in my example model. For example, I named them `title` and `image`, starting with a lower-case letter. Among other benefits, that way you can see which is which more easily when you reorder them.

Here is a specification window in a professional tool called MagicDraw, where you can drag properties into the order you like:

[image]

You could change the order to say that the image comes before the title.

P.S., in an analysis model, if this ordering is a rule that's important in the problem domain, I would actually show an explicit association between `Image` and `Title` having association ends called something like `comes before` and `comes after`.

Comment: All well and good but there isn't a way to express the order of properties in the diagram itself.  It's an element of UML for which there is no corresponding diagram element (at least not one that I'm aware of). Even in MagicDraw you can't reorder all properties.  You can reorder attributes and you can reorder association ends but both sets are mutually exclusive and you can't mix them.  Fact is, the OP wanted to embed characteristics of a view into the model, which isn't _really_ what UML is for...even if you can kludge it in.